# the nature of git distribution

Tags: git, dvcs

If I do the following and *only* the following:

1. Create a personal repo on my PC (lets call it `A`)
2. Create a bare repo on a server (call it `B`)
3. remote add the bare repo to the personal repo (i.e. remote add `B` to `A`)
4. Clone `B` to a third computer (call this new personal repo `C`)

Now let us imagine that the server is destroyed so `B` no longer exists. In this scenario, if I push changes from `A`, can `C` still fetch those changes?

Or in other words does git push changes to remotes in a 'chained' manner, or do all remotes on a 'cluster' know about each other?

Comment: No. Each client in the "cluster" is isolated. `A` will never be able to see changes made on `C` without `B` to do the handshake. At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: *[...] if I push changes from A, can C still fetch those changes?* `A` won't know about `C` unless you add it as a remote of the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you never pushed any changes from `A` to `B`. So while `A` knows about `B`, `B` doesn't know anything about `A` nor does it contain any data from it.

Pushing from `A` to `B` would work from `A` (since `A` knows about `B`). The data would end up in `B`. No matter how many other repos know about `B`, `B` won't push the changes further. Instead the other repos would have to *pull* them *from* `B`.

If we assume that you pushed at least once from `A` to `B` and cloned to `C`, you could add `C` as a remote to `A` and then push to it. But `C` will never "magically" contain data that are pushed between the other repos. Data is only copied into a repo when someone pushes to it or pulls from somewhere.

So for every operation, only 2 repos are ever involved.

Comment: Hang on, so if I add `C` as a remote to `A`, then when I push from `A` will the changes go to `C` without `C` having to fetch first?

Comment: Yes. Git makes absolutely no difference between repos. It doesn't matter for it that you think "`B` is a server" and "`C` is another client." You can also add `A` to `C` and then pull/fetch from `C` to achieve exactly the same result as `git push C master` on `A`.

Comment: So the personal vs bare repository doesn't change the push/pull behaviour of the repository? Also I thought you would never get pushed changes without fetching first?

Comment: All repos are equal regarding fetch/pull/push. The file layout on the hard disk is sometimes a bit different (bare repos don't support checking out the files). As I said, to transfer data, you must somehow initiate a fetch/pull/push. That copies data between the two repos which are involved in the operation in the direction which the operation defines. fetch/pull is always remote -> local and pull is always the other way around.

Comment: In the end, `git push C master` on `A` does the same as `git fetch A master` on `C`. But one of the two is often much more convenient (making `C` fetch when you sit in front of `A`...)

Comment: Thanks, I've been using git extensions GUI in windows so I didn't realize you push to / pull from a specific remote. I thought you just push and pull and those operations go affect all remotes equally :/ guess I'm still far from understanding git...

Comment: Think of Git as a versioned file system with manual distribution: You can add a folder (or rather the files inside) and then copy updates between two nodes by clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

No. `A` will list `B` as a remote and `C` will list `B` as a remote, but they won't know about each other. If you destroy `B` and don't add another remote to `A`, then there's nowhere for you to push changes from `A` *to*.